convergence of sequence of approximations
let x = ε be the root of f(x) = 0 and let i be an interval containing the point x = ε . let φ(x) and φ'(x) be continuous in i,  where φ(x) is defined by the equation x = φ(x)  which is equivalen tot f(x) = 0. then in |φ'(x) | < 1 for all x in I, the sequence of approximations x0,x1,x2,...,xn defined by x(n+1) = φ(xn) , converges to the root
i have got this question and here is my approach but i am confused
: Show that the sequence of approximations is within the interval I.
Since x0 is an initial approximation, it is within the interval I. Now, let's assume that xn is within I. We will show that x(n+1) = φ(xn) is also within I.
Using the mean value theorem, there exists a c between xn and x(n+1) such that:
x(n+1) - xn = φ'(c) * (x(n+1) - xn)
Since |φ'(c)| < 1, we can rearrange the equation as:
x(n+1) = xn + φ'(c) * (x(n+1) - xn)
Now, since xn and x(n+1) are both in I, their difference (x(n+1) - xn) is small. Therefore, the term φ'(c) * (x(n+1) - xn) is even smaller, which implies that x(n+1) is very close to xn. Thus, x(n+1) is also within the interval I.

This makes no sense at all: "where φ(x) is defined by the equation x = φ(x) which is equivalen tot f(x) = 0." Also, please use Mathjax to format your mathematics.
